# Basic arithmetic with prepared statements

Tags: android, sqlite, prepared-statement

I have a fairly simple query that I want to use a prepared statement for:

```
SQLiteStatement stmt = 
    db.compileStatement("UPDATE items SET totalcount=totalcount-? WHERE id=?");
stmt.bindLong(0, count);
stmt.binString(1, "someID");
```

but it gives me a [SQLiteBindOrColumnIndexOutOfRangeException](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteBindOrColumnIndexOutOfRangeException.html).

How can I bind the value in a simple arithmetic statement? I googled a little on this exception and did find solutions for `LIKE`, but not for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To quote the [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteProgram.html#bindLong%28int,%20long%29):

> **Parameters**
>    *index*  The 1-based index to the parameter to bind

The parameter numbers must be 1 and 2.

Comment: Ah yes. Ran into that when figuring it out for the first time, and not now. Know the reason for this very strange inconsistency?

Comment: Why would this be inconsistent?

Comment: Because the entire language is zero-based.

Comment: This is just a wrapper for the SQLite C API, where [0 is a special error value](http://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/bind_parameter_index.html).